# "process_noise_covariance" and "initial_estimate_covariance" in EKF-global and EKF-local

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi everyone,

in EKF-global and EKF-local related to the robot-localization package, there are two parameters: "process_noise_covariance" and "initial_estimate_covariance".
how can i tune "process_noise_covariance" and "initial_estimate_covariance" for a 4wheel differential robot. the values on the diagonal are based on what?
I would be grateful if someone explain to me these two parameters.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/391483/%22process_noise_covariance%22-and-%22initial_estimate_covariance%22-in-ekf-global-and-ekf-local/) by [Delbina](https://answers.ros.org/users/74099/delbina/) on ROS Answers with karma: 109 on 2021-11-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @Masoum, the following are definitions from the [robot_localization package](http://docs.ros.org/en/kinetic/api/robot_localization/html/state_estimation_nodes.html#process-noise-covariance)

> The **estimate covariance**, commonly
> denoted **P or R**, defines the error in the
> current state estimate. The parameter
> allows users to set the initial value
> for the matrix, which will affect how
> quickly the filter converges. For
> example, if users set the value at
> position [0,0] to a very small value,
> e.g., 1e-12, and then attempt to fuse
> measurements of X position with a high
> variance value for X, then the filter
> will be very slow to “trust” those
> measurements, and the time required
> for convergence will increase. Again,
> users should take care with this
> parameter. When only fusing velocity
> data (e.g., no absolute pose
> information), users will likely not
> want to set the initial covariance
> values for the absolute pose variables
> to large numbers. This is because
> those errors are going to grow without
> bound (owing to the lack of absolute
> pose measurements to reduce the
> error), and starting them with large
> values will not benefit the state
> estimate.
>
> The **process noise covariance**, commonly
> denoted Q, is used to model
> uncertainty in the prediction stage of
> the filtering algorithms. It can be
> difficult to tune, and has been
> exposed as a parameter for easier
> customization. This parameter can be
> left alone, but you will achieve
> superior results by tuning it. In
> general, the larger the value for **Q**
> relative to the variance for a given
> variable in an input message, the
> faster the filter will converge to the
> value in the measurement.

There are many methods to initialize the covariances. As stated in the robot_localization package, one approach is to use trial and error, others call it engineer's intuition. You can start by working with very small values and measure the results based on time to converge. For the process noise covariance, you can tune by starting 'high' and lowering until you are satisfied. The disadvantage of this method is that is time consuming and there are many combinations possible. You will be optimizing one parameter at the time.

If you are looking for a systematic approach, you can use the proposed method in this paper:
https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1702/1702.00884.pdf. The paper proposes for example to use the ratio of Q/R looking for smallest SME (square mean error) to find the best performance, rather than optimizing one parameter at the time. But it's not the only proposed approach in this paper, there are more. I'd highly recommend reading it.

Another approach I have seen is to use PSO (Particle Swarm Optimization) for EKF tuning with great results: https://www.naun.org/main/NAUN/circuitssystemssignal/cssp-101.pdf. This is a more consistent approach to finding parameters, however is more complex to implement.

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2021-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Delbina](https://answers.ros.org/users/74099/delbina/) on 2021-11-24**:
Thanks a lot, @osilva,
one more question, what would happen if these two parameters are not set properly? I mean what is the impact in the result that we can say it is because of these two parameters!

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-11-24**:
Glad it helped. Pls accept the answer so we can close the cycle.

Regarding your last question. With respect to R if not properly ser it can quickly get out of bounds and will not converge. Q will affect the time of convergence

**Comment by [Delbina](https://answers.ros.org/users/74099/delbina/) on 2022-02-10**:
hi @osilva,
what are the values in the diagonal of "process_noise_covariance" and "initial_estimate_covariance" indicative of?
and we have defined a number of odometry information, in ekf-se-map, i mean odometry of GPS, wheel odometer, imu, and odometry information from my slam. so i want to know process_noise_covariance" and "initial_estimate_covariance" are related to which of these information?

thanks